# case when results as left join condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Table 1

```
Staff   category hours cost
1     Cleaning   5    20
1     Scrubbing  6    30
1     Cleaning   8    40
2     Scrubbing  4    30
```

table 2

`

```
Staff  type vendor category 
 1      part  A Cleaning
 1      full  b Cleaning 
 1      full  c Scrubbing 
...’
```

To join these two tables I added a new col “type”:

```
Case when table1.hours=8
Then ”full”
Else ”part”
End as “type”

From table1 
Left join table2 on type=table2.type
And Table 1.staff =table2.staff
```

And   Table1.category=table 2.category

My desired outcome is

```
Staff  category   Cost vendor type
  1      Cleaning  20  A.     Part
  1      Cleaning  40  B.     Full
  1      Scrubbing 30  C.    Part
```

However the type=table2.type condition didn’t work so it became

```
Staff  category   Cost vendor type
  1      Cleaning  20  A.     Part
  1      Cleaning  20  B.     part
  1      cleaning  40. A      Full
  1.      Cleaning 40  B.     Full
```

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: You need to `AND` or `OR` the join conditions

Comment: I think the problem is your `JOIN`.  You don't have a unique mapping between the tables.

Comment: Your *desired outcome* is not consistent to your sample data.

Comment: DBMS? I use bigquery in google. Join should be unique If all conditions are fullfiled(I.e category staff -and type )

Answer (score 2):

If I have not understood, you want an implementation that creates a column in table1 and then joins with table2 on the condition table1.category = table2.category and table1.type = table2.type. If that's the case you could try with the following:

```
SELECT t1.Staff, t1.category, t1.cost, table2.vendor, t1.type
FROM (
  SELECT *, CASE WHEN table1.hours = 8 THEN "full" ELSE "part" END as type
  FROM table1
) t1
INNER JOIN table2
ON t1.category = table2.category
AND t1.type = table2.type
AND t1.staff = table2.staff
```

Comment: i am glad you finally realized what was wrong with your original answer! meantime it is still not 100% correct and if you will actually make the final correction - you will end up with what is in my answer :o)

Comment: that was not my point - even though you ended up with what is in my answer! my point was that voting up clearly wrong answers is not good practice. this is not about you - this is about those who irresponsibly voted up your initial answer

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT staff, category, cost, vendor, type
FROM (
  SELECT *, IF(hours = 8, 'full', 'part') AS type 
  FROM `project.dataset.table1`
) t1 
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table2` t2 
USING (type, staff, category)
```